# getElementById returns null except in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with the javascript document.getElementById function. The problem is, that every browser, except Internet Explorer, is getting an error that document.getElementById is null.

For Example Firefox:

TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

The getElementById-Function appears *after* the declaration of the button, so it shouldn't be a problem, that the function doesn't know what the ID-element is.

This is an extract of the script with the regarding code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Timeline</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" id="myform" onsubmit="window.location.reload();">
<input type="hidden" id="client_timestamp" name="client_timestamp" />
<button name= "subm_myform" type="submit" >Send My Time</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
// ------- where the error occurs ----------------
document.getElementById('subm_myform').style.visibility='hidden';
var mySync = setTimeout( function () {document.getElementById('subm_myform').click()} ,60000);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: `< button name= "subm_myform">` / `getElementById('subm_myform')` - maybe IE conflates `name` and `id` for some backwards compatibility reasons? I there's no element with `id="subm_myform"` in the code you've posted.

Comment: Your button has a `name` of `subm_myform`, not an ID.  If IE doesn't find an element by ID, it tries to do so by name.  At least in older versions of IE.  (we actually had to shim the getElementByID function to so this in every browser for some of our code base once... _shudder_)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are fetching DOM element by `id` and looks like you DOM element has not any `id` attribute. It should be `<button name= "subm_myform" type="submit" id="subm_myform" >Send My Time</button>`.

This is a 'feature' of IE. Their implementation of `getElementById` initially searches for elements with the given `id` attribute. If none are found, it then searches for elements by the `name` attribute.

If you want to find elements by their name, use the `getElementsByName()` method instead.

Comment: Thanks everyone for these fast answers! I marked this question, because it was extensive and explains why it's working in IE.

Answer (score 2):

There is no form element with id subm_myform, you have one with name. Fix that in the code as:

```
<button id= "subm_myform" type="submit" >Send My Time</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById` is not suppose to look for the `name`. It's weird that Internet Explorer does not crash. Maybe it try to find with the name if it can't find with the `id`.

Add an `id` to your button to fix the problem :

```
<button name="subm_myform" id="subm_myform" type="submit" >Send My Time</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
<button name= "subm_myform" type="submit" >Send My Time</button>
```

has no id, try this

```
<button id="subm_myform" name="subm_myform" type="submit" >Send My Time</button>
```

Answer (score -4):

The problem is you want to get an id but you didn't add the #
And the other problem is you give it a name attribute, you need to set it to id="subm_myform"

Try

```
<button id= "subm_myform" type="submit" >
```

document.getElementById('#subm_myform').style.visibility='hidden';

Comment: this is not a jQuery statement but vanilla JS.  the # is implicit within using getElementById();

The correct fix was to use an ID on the button and not use the name and hope.

Comment: Yes you're right. I didn't thinked about that because I worked always with jQuery. Thanks for the hint